# Add information to matplotlib Navigation toolbar/status bar?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm plotting a 2D-array with matplotlib. On the lower right corner of the window the x and y coordinates of the cursor are showed. How can I add information to this status bar about the data underneath the cursor, e.g., instead of 'x=439.501  y=317.744' it would show 'x,y: [440,318]  data: 100'? Can I somehow get my hands on this Navigation toolbar and write my own message to be showed?

I've managed to add my own event handler for 'button_press_event', so that the data value is printed on the terminal window, but this approach just requires a lot of mouse clicking and floods the interactive session.

Comment: possible duplicate of [matplotlib values under cursor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14754931/matplotlib-values-under-cursor)

Comment: also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14349289/in-a-matplotlib-figure-window-with-imshow-how-can-i-remove-hide-or-redefine

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You simply need to re-assign `ax.format_coord`, the call back used to draw that label.

See [this example](http://matplotlib.org/examples/api/image_zcoord.html) from the documentation, as well as 
[In a matplotlib figure window (with imshow), how can I remove, hide, or redefine the displayed position of the mouse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14349289/in-a-matplotlib-figure-window-with-imshow-how-can-i-remove-hide-or-redefine/14351623#14351623) and [matplotlib values under cursor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14754931/matplotlib-values-under-cursor/14755358#14755358)

(code lifted directly from example)

```
"""
Show how to modify the coordinate formatter to report the image "z"
value of the nearest pixel given x and y
"""
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cm as cm

X = 10*np.random.rand(5,3)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.imshow(X, cmap=cm.jet, interpolation='nearest')

numrows, numcols = X.shape
def format_coord(x, y):
    col = int(x+0.5)
    row = int(y+0.5)
    if col>=0 and col<numcols and row>=0 and row<numrows:
        z = X[row,col]
        return 'x=%1.4f, y=%1.4f, z=%1.4f'%(x, y, z)
    else:
        return 'x=%1.4f, y=%1.4f'%(x, y)

ax.format_coord = format_coord
plt.show()
```

Comment: after all that googling, I still didn't find this one! thanks for the solution!

Comment: @northaholic If this solved your problem can you accept it (the big gray check mark on the left)