# Force update to matplotlib toolbar/status bar information

Tags: python, canvas, matplotlib

I've got a matplotlib plot in which I've modified the toolbar/status bar information much as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15876011/add-information-to-matplotlib-navigation-toolbar-status-bar). This works just fine and the necessary information is displayed as I need it.

However, I often need to update the plot (which is done by calling `draw()` on the canvas object) with new data. What happens though is that the toolbar/status bar information won't update until the mouse is moved again. I'd like this information to update as soon as the canvas is redrawn because some of this information is pertinent to the new plot.

My attempt at making this happen was to force a mouse motion event to trigger. I've tried to trigger the event from the canvas via `self.canvas.motion_notify_event(0,0)` but that doesn't seem to work well. I can see that the toolbar itself has a [`mouse_move`](http://matplotlib.org/api/backend_bases_api.html#matplotlib.backend_bases.NavigationToolbar2.mouse_move) method, but I don't know how to trigger it (or even if it's what I want to trigger).

**How can I force the toolbar/status bar information to update during a plot redraw without requiring the user to move their mouse slightly?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did a lot of digging and figured it out. The `motion_notify_event` method was what I was looking for, I was just using it wrong. You can fake matplotlib out and trigger a MouseEvent by using this function, which will then make matplotlib call all functions that respond to MouseEvents, including updating the toolbar/status bar information.

The key here is that I needed to trigger the MouseEvent as if it happened within the axes object, not the entire figure. The input to the function is the (x,y) pixel position of the event with respect to the lower left corner of the figure window. By using (0,0) as I did in my question, I was saying the mouse event happened at the lower left corner of the figure window, not on the axes itself. Matplotlib does not show toolbar/status bar information unless the cursor is on the axes.

What you can do then is pick some random pixel position on the axes and use that as the position. A simple way to pick such a pixel position is using [matplotlib transformations](http://matplotlib.org/users/transforms_tutorial.html).

The following now works for me:

```
canvas.motion_notify_event(*ax.transAxes.transform([0,0]))
```

Of course in my case I'm not displaying the data coordinates of the mouse, so your use cases may vary.